# Mutating two dependent values in loop

Tags: rust, ownership

I tried to read a file in a way that is performant enough for my purpose. I have a list of file ids, names and line indexes (ordered) and for each pair `(file_id, file_name, line_index)` I need to open the file, find the line by index and print.

To be more performant (I know the input is ordered) I'd like to cache the `BufReader` that reads by line and let the file stay open if possible.

```
fn main() {
    // positions in file
    // structure: (file_id, file_name, line_index_in_file)
    let positions = &vec![
        (1, String::from("file1"), 1), 
        (1, String::from("file1"), 2), 
        (1, String::from("file1"), 20), 
        (2, String::from("file2"), 15)];

    print_lines_from_file(&positions);
}

fn print_lines_from_file(found: &Vec<(i32, String, i32)>) {
    let mut last_file_id = -1;

    //let mut last_file_name = None;
    let mut open_file = None;
    let mut open_reader = None;

    for &(file_id, ref file_name, pos_in_file) in found {
        println!("{} {}", file_id, pos_in_file);

         if last_file_id < file_id {
            last_file_id = file_id;
            //last_file_name = file_ids.get(&file_id);

            if let Some(to_close) = open_file {
                drop(open_reader.unwrap());
                drop(to_close);
            }
            //let file = File::open(last_file_name.unwrap()).unwrap();
            let file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();
            open_file = Some(file);
            open_reader = Some(BufReader::new(&file));
        }

        // use reader to find the line in file and process
    }
}
```

I'm facing this problem:

```
main.rs:40:48: 40:52 error: `file` does not live long enough
main.rs:40             open_reader = Some(BufReader::new(&file));

main.rs:40:48: 40:52 error: use of moved value: `file` [E0382]
main.rs:40             open_reader = Some(BufReader::new(&file));
```

It's obvious (`file`'s lifetime is really short), but I don't know how to workaround it. 
The `BufReader` depends on `File`, but I need to close the `File` later in loop when `file_id` changes.

Also I don't feel very comfortable calling `drop` this way in loop as it looks to me like I try to fool the compiler. Is that approach ok?

**Please even if you know better solution (e.g. how to close the file through `BufReader`, I would appreciate the general insight how to solve it).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `File` by value to the `BufReader`. This way you only have a single variable that owns a file handle. You can use `take` on the `Option` to move the inner value out of it and leave a `None` behind. This way you ensure that the file handle is freed before the next one is taken (so if you re-open the same file it doesn't panic)

```
let mut open_reader = None;

for &(file_id, ref file_name, pos_in_file) in found {
    println!("{} {}", file_id, pos_in_file);

     if last_file_id < file_id {
        last_file_id = file_id;
        //last_file_name = file_ids.get(&file_id);

        // take the value out of the `open_reader` to make sure that
        // the file is closed, so we don't panic if the next statement
        // tries to open the same file again.
        open_reader.take();
        //let file = File::open(last_file_name.unwrap()).unwrap();
        let file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();
        open_reader = Some(BufReader::new(file));
    }

    // use reader to find the line in file and process
}
```

Comment: The explicit `drop` isn't needed, it seems.

Comment: @Shepmaster: but it's more explicit, that's why I included it. Alternatively one could add a comment stating the intend... Which is probably better :)

Comment: I edited the text to include a comment instead of the `drop`

Comment: Still I don't understand exactly what's the mechanism that ensures closing the reader. Is it because we take the value from `Option`, don't store it anywhere, so rust is clever enough to make a cleanup and release it immediatelly?

Comment: correct. You could simply overwrite the `open_reader`, but that would fail if you'd open the same file again, because the file is already open.

Answer (score 2):

You're giving ownership of the file to the `BufReader` (which is obvious since it's passed by value), rather than lending it - it's now `BufReader`'s job to close the file.  When it's dropped, the `File` it owns will be dropped in turn; so you can just lose `open_file` completely.

The compiler is successfully stopping you from possibly destroying the file under the `BufReader`'s feet.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to cache the `BufReader` that reads by line and let the file stay open if possible.

The *easiest* way to do that is to group the data ahead of time:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn print_lines_from_file(found: &[(i32, String, i32)]) {
    let mut index = HashMap::new();
    for line in found {
        let name = &line.1;
        index.entry(name).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(line);
    }

    for (file_name, lines) in &index {
        let file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();

        for &&(file_id, _, line_index) in lines {
            // do something with `file`
            println!("processing ID {} ({}) line {}", file_id, file_name, line_index);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this frees you from having to have a special sentinel value for `file_id` (which could also be done with an `Option`). Additionally, even though you say that the data is sorted, this allows you to handle the cases where the `file_id`s are not. You could also handle the case of unsorted `line_index`es by sorting the vector after it's complete.

Additionally:

1. You have a double reference in `main` — you don't need to say `&vec![...]`.
2. You should accept a `&[T]` instead of a `&Vec<T>`.

---

An even more beautiful solution, IMHO, is to use [itertools](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/), specifically [`group_by_lazy`](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by_lazy):

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn main() {
    // structure: (file_id, file_name, line_index_in_file)
    let positions = [
        (1, String::from("file1"), 1),
        (1, String::from("file1"), 2),
        (1, String::from("file1"), 20),
        (2, String::from("file2"), 15)
    ];

    print_lines_from_file(&positions);
}

fn print_lines_from_file(found: &[(i32, String, i32)]) {
    for (filename, positions) in &found.iter().group_by_lazy(|pos| &pos.1) {
        println!("Opening file {}", filename);
        // let file = File::open(file_name).expect("Failed to open the file");
        // let file = BufReader::new(file);

        for &(id, _, line) in positions {
            println!("Processing ID {}, line {}", id, line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice idea. It takes more memory than necessary, but it might be useful. (there is more data than in the sample I made via `vec![..]` - I wated to make the sample simple enough)

Comment: @stej new version that looks pretty nice ;-)

Comment: Great idea. I accepted ker's answer as it is more related to my question, but yours solution is nice. I would upvoted it twice if possible ;)